# Jar in executable Jar: jorg.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I) org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

I am successfully using a Java command line program that I wrote
that uses the Apache POI  file to read a Microsoft
Word (.docx) file and mail it.  I wish to package it  as an executable jar.

I am creating this
by taking each jar that my application needs and expanding with `jar -xvf.`

Stackoverflow question 183292 describes the techniques that one can use when
one needs to put a library "jar in a jar."

Unfortunately, I am getting the error below when I run it.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:145)
    at m4.main(m4.java:273)
```

The last thing I did before creating the jar fille was to expand
(with `jar -xvf`) `xmlbeans-5.1.3.jar`.
I then rejarred everything (my application and the results of jaring all
the other files.)

Question 20799326 on StackOverflow.com explains that this
symptom is caused by multiple xml beans jar files on the class path.
However, since the executable jar should only see expanded versions, 
I do not believe that could be a problem.

Question 183292 further said that expanding one jar to create another could 
lead to issues with package name conflicts.

(But this "should not happen if people use proper
packages, ..."  However, I certainly believe that Apache does use the standard
package convention...

I expanded 5.1 version last.
That should replace any old version that might have 
been lying around in the directory. 
(Just in case, I tried removing the old `org/apache/xmlbeans`
directory and then redoing the jar.  Did not help.)

After I expanded the jar's, I did a `ls -R`
I take the liberty of attaching the list, on the offchance, someone might
see something there.  I did abbreviate those parts that seem least relevant
with ellipsis.

```
m4:
com
Debug
javax
LICENSE.txt
m4$1.class
m4$AddressMap.class
m4.class
m4$CmdLineConst.class
Manifest.txt
META-INF
NOTICE.txt
org
resolver.jar
schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans

m4/com:
microsoft
sun

m4/com/microsoft:
schemas

m4/com/microsoft/schemas:
compatibility
office
vml

...
m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office:
excel
office
visio
x2006

m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office/excel:
    ...
m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office/x2006:
digsig
encryption
keyEncryptor

m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office/x2006/digsig:
CTSignatureInfoV1.class
CTSignatureInfoV1$Factory.class
....

m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office/x2006/digsig/impl:
...

m4/com/microsoft/schemas/office/x2006/encryption:
CTDataIntegrity.class


....
m4/com/sun:
mail

m4/com/sun/mail:
handlers
iap
imap
pop3
smtp
util

m4/com/sun/mail/handlers:
image_gif.class
image_jpeg.class
message_rfc822.class
multipart_mixed.class
text_html.class
text_plain.class
text_xml.class

m4/com/sun/mail/iap:
Argument.class
AString.class
Atom.class
....

m4/com/sun/mail/imap:
ACL.class
AppendUID.class
DefaultFolder$1.class
...

m4/com/sun/mail/imap/protocol:
BASE64MailboxDecoder.class
BASE64MailboxEncoder.class
BODY.class
...

....

m4/com/sun/mail/smtp:
DigestMD5.class
SMTPAddressFailedException.class
....

m4/com/sun/mail/util:
ASCIIUtility.class
BASE64DecoderStream.class
...

m4/Debug:  (This is my class)
Debug.class
Debug.java

m4/javax:
mail

m4/javax/mail:
Address.class
AuthenticationFailedException.class
Authenticator.class
BodyPart.class
....

m4/javax/mail/event:
ConnectionAdapter.class
ConnectionEvent.class
....

m4/javax/mail/internet:
AddressException.class
AsciiOutputStream.class
CachedDataHandler.class
....

m4/javax/mail/search:
AddressStringTerm.class
AddressTerm.class
AndTerm.class
....

m4/javax/mail/util:
...

m4/META-INF:
INDEX.LIST
javamail.charset.map
javamail.default.address.map
javamail.default.providers
LICENSE
LICENSE.txt
mailcap
MANIFEST.MF
maven
NOTICE
NOTICE.txt
services
SUN_MICR.RSA
SUN_MICR.SF
xmlbeans.bnd

m4/META-INF/maven:
org.apache.commons
org.ow2.jonas.osgi

m4/META-INF/maven/org.apache.commons:
commons-collections4
commons-compress

....

m4/org:
apache
etsi
openxmlformats
w3
w3c

m4/org/apache:
commons
env
poi
xml
xmlbeans

m4/org/apache/commons:
collections4
compress

m4/org/apache/commons/collections4:
ArrayStack.class
ArrayUtils.class
bag
Bag.class
BagUtils.class
bidimap
...

m4/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag:
AbstractBagDecorator.class
AbstractMapBag$BagIterator.class
AbstractMapBag.class


.....

m4/org/apache/commons/compress:
archivers
changes
....

m4/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers:
ar
ArchiveEntry.class
ArchiveException.class
ArchiveInputStream.class
....
tar
zip

...

m4/org/apache/env:
WhichFactory.properties
WhichJar.properties

m4/org/apache/poi:
common
ddf
EmptyFileException.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/common:
usermodel

m4/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel:
fonts
Hyperlink.class
HyperlinkType.class

m4/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/fonts:
FontCharset.class
FontFamily.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/ddf:
AbstractEscherOptRecord$1.class
AbstractEscherOptRecord.class
DefaultEscherRecordFactory.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/extractor:
ole2
OLE2ExtractorFactory.class
POIOLE2TextExtractor.class
POITextExtractor.class

m4/org/apache/poi/extractor/ole2:
OLE2ScratchpadExtractorFactory.class

....


m4/org/apache/poi/ooxml:
extractor
POIXMLDocument.class
...

m4/org/apache/poi/ooxml/extractor:
CommandLineTextExtractor.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/ooxml/util:
DocumentHelper$1.class
DocumentHelper.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/openxml4j:
exceptions
opc
util

.....

m4/org/apache/poi/sl/usermodel:
AbstractColorStyle.class
AutoNumberingScheme$1.class
AutoNumberingScheme.class
...
TextShape$TextPlaceholder.class
VerticalAlignment.class

m4/org/apache/poi/ss:
excelant
extractor
format
formula
SpreadsheetVersion.class
usermodel
util

m4/org/apache/poi/ss/excelant:
antlib.xml
ExcelAntEvaluateCell.class
ExcelAntHandlerTask.class
ExcelAntPrecision.class
....

m4/org/apache/poi/ss/excelant/util:
ExcelAntEvaluationResult.class
ExcelAntWorkbookUtil.class
ExcelAntWorkbookUtilFactory.class

m4/org/apache/poi/ss/extractor:
EmbeddedData.class
EmbeddedExtractor$BiffExtractor.class
...

m4/org/apache/poi/ss/format:
CellDateFormatter$1.class
CellDateFormatter.class
CellDateFormatter$DatePartHandler.class
CellElapsedFormatter$1.class
...

m4/org/apache/poi/ss/formula:
atp
BaseFormulaEvaluator$1.class
BaseFormulaEvaluator.class
...
WorkbookDependentFormula.class
WorkbookEvaluator$1.class
WorkbookEvaluator.class
WorkbookEvaluatorProvider.class

...

....

m4/org/apache/poi/xddf:
usermodel

m4/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel:
BlackWhiteMode.class
chart
CompoundLine.class
...
XDDFRadarChartData.class
XDDFRadarChartData$Series.class
XDDFScatterChartData.class
XDDFScatterChartData$Series.class
XDDFSeriesAxis.class
XDDFValueAxis.class

....

....

m4/org/apache/poi/xwpf:
extractor
model
usermodel

m4/org/apache/poi/xwpf/extractor:
XWPFWordExtractor.class

m4/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model:
WMLHelper.class
XWPFCommentsDecorator.class
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.class
XWPFParagraphDecorator.class

m4/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel:
BodyElementType.class
BodyType.class
Borders.class
BreakClear.class
...
XWPFTable$1.class
XWPFTable$Border.class
...

m4/org/apache/xml:
resolver

m4/org/apache/xml/resolver:
apps
Catalog.class
CatalogEntry.class
...
Resolver.class
tools
Version.class

m4/org/apache/xml/resolver/apps:
resolver.class
xparse.class
XParseError.class
xread.class

m4/org/apache/xml/resolver/etc:
catalog.dtd
catalog.rng
catalog.xsd

...

m4/org/apache/xmlbeans:
BindingConfig.class
CDataBookmark.class
DelegateXmlObject.class
...
XmlUnsignedShort$Factory.class
XmlValidationError.class

m4/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl:
common
config
inst2xsd
jam
piccolo
regex
richParser
schema
soap
store
tool
util
validator
values
xb
xpathgen
xsd2inst

m4/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/common:
ConcurrentReaderHashMap$1.class
ConcurrentReaderHashMap$BarrierLock.class
ConcurrentReaderHashMap.class
ConcurrentReaderHashMap$Entry.class
...
XPath.class
XPath$CompilationContext.class
XPath$ExecutionContext.class
XPath$ExecutionContext$PathContext.class
XPath$Selector.class
XPath$Step.class
XPath$XPathCompileException.class

...

m4/org/etsi:
uri

m4/org/etsi/uri:
x01903

m4/org/etsi/uri/x01903:
v13

m4/org/etsi/uri/x01903/v13:
AnyType.class
AnyType$Factory.class
CertIDListType.class
CertIDListType$Factory.class
CertIDType.class
CertIDType$Factory.class
...
XAdESTimeStampType.class
XAdESTimeStampType$Factory.class

m4/org/etsi/uri/x01903/v13/impl:
AnyTypeImpl.class
CertIDListTypeImpl.class
CertIDTypeImpl.class
CertificateValuesTypeImpl.class
...
UnsignedPropertiesTypeImpl.class
UnsignedSignaturePropertiesTypeImpl.class
XAdESTimeStampTypeImpl.class

m4/org/openxmlformats:
schemas

m4/org/openxmlformats/schemas:
drawingml
officeDocument
presentationml
spreadsheetml
wordprocessingml
xpackage

....
...

m4/org/openxmlformats/schemas/officeDocument:
x2006

m4/org/openxmlformats/schemas/officeDocument/x2006:
customProperties
docPropsVTypes
extendedProperties
relationships

...

m4/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main:
CalcChainDocument.class
CalcChainDocument$Factory.class
ChartsheetDocument.class
ChartsheetDocument$Factory.class
CommentsDocument.class
...
StylesDocument.class
StylesDocument$Factory.class
STZoom$Enum.class

....
m4/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/javaname/org/apache/xmlbeans:
impl

m4/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/javaname/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl:
xb

m4/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/javaname/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xb:
ltgfmt
substwsdl
xmlconfig
xmlschema
xsdownload
xsdschema

m4/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/javaname/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xb/ltgfmt:
Code.xsb
FileDesc
FileDesc.xsb
TestCase
   ... (rest is all schemaorg stuff)
```

Comment: From where have you got `xmlbeans-5.1.3.jar`? Last version is [xmlbeans/3.0.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.0.2), see also [XMLBeans Download](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), and `apache poi version 4.0.0` [also recommends using this version](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components).

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans513jar.htm

Comment: That seems to be `org.ow2.jonas.osgi` - you need `org.apache.xmlbeans` instead, which Axel has linked to the latest version details of

Answer (score 0):

Same error here but loading an excel file, just upgrade my XMLBeans from 2.3.0 to 3.1.0 and all work really nice.

download here:

```
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/xmlbeans/release/bin/xmlbeans-bin-3.1.0.zip
```